# C++ WinRT - Possible to access XAML control TextBlock under thread created via std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a C++/WinRT XAML program with a function **_tproc( p )**, where p is **MainPage* p** in short.

The compile process is ok but failed if calling via std::thread creation.

Here is the source code:

**MainPage.H**

```
struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
{
    TextBlock           m_tbx;
    TranslateTransform  m_pos;
    int                 m_x;
    int                 m_y;
    int                 m_itest;

    MainPage();
    int32_t MyProperty  ();
    void    MyProperty  (int32_t value); 
    int     f_iOnInit   ();
};
```

**MainPage.cpp**

```
void _tproc ( winrt::WINRT_DEMO::implementation::MainPage* p = nullptr) 
{
    if (p == nullptr) return;
    auto x{ 500 };
    auto y{ 500 };

    // NOTE: Instructions below caused error if _tproc() is 
    //       called via std::thread  
    p->m_pos.X(x); 
    p->m_pos.Y(y); 
    p->m_tbx.RenderTransform(p->m_pos); 
}

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    f_iOnInit();
}

int32_t MainPage::MyProperty()
{
    throw hresult_not_implemented();
}

void MainPage::MyProperty(int32_t /* value */)
{
    throw hresult_not_implemented();
}

int MainPage::f_iOnInit ()
{
    m_tbx.FontFamily( Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily( L"Segoe UI Semibold" ) );
    m_tbx.FontSize(24.0);
    m_tbx.Foreground( SolidColorBrush( Colors::Orange() ) );
    m_tbx.VerticalAlignment( VerticalAlignment::Center );
    m_tbx.HorizontalAlignment( HorizontalAlignment::Center );
    m_tbx.TextAlignment( TextAlignment::Left );              
    m_tbx.Text( L"Hello World!" );

    this->Content().as<Panel>().Children().Append( m_tbx );

    // Calling _tproc() below is fine.
    //_tproc( this ); 

    // Error occurred, explained within _tproc()
    std::thread t( _tproc, this ); 
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

For references, the runtime error page is captured [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wiyv6j9lx7t3oe/UWP%20-%20XAML%20control%20access%20error%20via%20thread%20creation.jpg?dl=0).

Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure the control can be called from a thread? Did you initialize the runtime environment from the thread?

Comment: I am new to C++ WinRT, control within_tproc() can be called directly as function ( eg. _tproc(this)" but not as thread. Please advise how to initialize the runtime environment from the thread means ?

Comment: You might need to `winrt::init_apartment(apartment_type::single_threaded);
WindowsXamlManager windowsXamlManager = WindowsXamlManager::InitializeForCurrentThread();` and/or `CoInitializeEx()`. Even so, some controls are not meant to be called from another thread and usually, GUI components are such controls.

Comment: Ic, I found myself is lacking the understanding XAML foundation and COM, I means where do I starts in order to know there is a need of WindowsXamlManager::InitializeForCurrentThread() and CoInitializeEx() as it seems hard to find a book or references for WinRT ?

Even the site [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) I found hard to understand.

Will it be ok for you to point me to the right track so I can properly begin from there ?

Comment: Manual thread management is unusual in the Windows Runtime. Is there a particular reason, why you want to use `std::thread` (instead of coroutines)?

Comment: yes is true, I just wanna test UWP XAML as under Embarcadero FMX/FireMonkey is possible. Although both were with same advise not to access UI components under normal thread, but it seems FMX had little flexibility here. Anyhow, I resolved the issues using XAML timer routine then it works at 30fps.